# Does Google Maps API V2 API require android 4.2.2?

Tags: android, google-maps

I've been using the V1 MapViewfor all my apps.  I thought I should look into going to the Google Maps Android API V2 and began following the tutorial at [This Page](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/intro) Of course, like most things android, the tutorial process has enough bugs or omissions that it doesn't work. Further research found that few others can manage to make it work either.

While doing that research, however, I tripped on to [This Page](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) that says:

> If you want to test your app on the emulator, expand the directory for Android 4.2.2 (API 17) or a higher version, select Google APIs, and install it. Then create a new AVD with Google APIs as the platform target.
>   Note: Only Android 4.2.2 and higher versions of the Google APIs platform include Google Play services.

I understand that the V2 API operates through Google Play Services so does this mean that my app can't target older android versions if I use the V2 API?

Thanks, Gary

Comment: you can target older versions. but test it on a real devce

Comment: The Google Maps v2 API supports any device having Android 2.2 and above. Also, it must have the latest version of Google Play Store which has the Google Play Services along with it. So, that means the minimumSDKversion in the Manifest.xml cannot go below 8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it does not require 4.2.2. That documentation you're referencing pertains only to emulation. Prior the the emulator/Google APIs add on for 4.2.2, Google Play services was not included. If you want to test your maps integration on Android versions <4.2.2, you need to use a real device.

Answer (score 1):

the reason you can only test it on 4.2.2 in the emulator is because that version comes with google play services.

google play service works on anything 2.2 and up as long as the device has google play services installed